# Raster does not appear in the correct place in QGIS

Tags: raster

I am trying to overlap different maps (landuse, hydrographic...) and I have problems when I try to overlap the type of soil map. I have downloaded it in raster format and when I load it in my project it does not appear in the same place as the other maps even if I put the same coordinate system.

How can I fix this? And if I can´t fix it, how can I change the coordinates of the map?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the data? How is it misaligned?

Comment: You can manually georeference the raster like in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaZ2bt2AxUg&t=186s What type of raster are you working with? TIFF, JPG?

Comment: It is a really strange raster since it is a .adf

Comment: I have requested the information from European soil database, and I don´t really understand the data that they sent me because all the files are zipped with .adf files. Maybe the problem is that?

Comment: That is possible.  I have never worked with an .adf file before.   In the QGIS - Raster - Georeferencer there is the "Openraster" button.    Give it a try.  It might work.

Comment: Which software are you working with?  ArcGIS, QGIS or something else?

Comment: If you have an ancient Grid raster (.adf), the first thing you should do is convert it to something modern, like GeoTIFF. I doubt the projection was retained in the original data transfer, so that's the next step: Define a correct spatial reference. From there, you should be in a safe starting point for other operations.